# Networkx 2.2: degree_assortativity_coefficient with weights

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have got the following error when I am using with weights:

```
 outIn=nx.degree_assortativity_coefficient(net, x='out', y='in', weight='weight')
```

The error is

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/assortativity/mixing.py", line 160, in degree_mixing_matrix
    mapping = {x: x for x in range(m + 1)}

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

It works without the weights!
What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some test I discovered that edge weights have to be integers.

See

*M. E. J. Newman, Mixing patterns in networks, Physical Review E, 67 026126, 2003*

for futher information on the assortativity algorithm.